# Crawl URL file to get final destination URL after redirects?

Tags: python

I have a text file as follows

```
http://url.com/r/GFDGDFG
http://url.com/r/A32512F
http://url.com/r/AWDRE25
http://url.com/r/AGBFD35
http://url.com/r/NFG4622
```

Is there a way to use python (Trying to get some simple script on my linux box) To crawl each url (Load it) and get the final url? Each url/link is a redirect and I want to get the url after the redirects.

Comment: Use `response.url` in module `requests`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

urls = '''http://url.com/r/GFDGDFG
http://url.com/r/A32512F
http://url.com/r/AWDRE25
http://url.com/r/AGBFD35
http://url.com/r/NFG4622'''

for x in urls.splitlines():
    r = requests.get(x)
    print x, '=>', r.url
```

result:

```
http://url.com/r/GFDGDFG => http://lyrics.url.com
http://url.com/r/A32512F => http://lyrics.url.com
http://url.com/r/AWDRE25 => http://lyrics.url.com
http://url.com/r/AGBFD35 => http://lyrics.url.com
http://url.com/r/NFG4622 => http://lyrics.url.com
```

Comment: this is perfect, how can I save this to file line by line?

Comment: Use `open(..., 'w')` and `write(... + '\n')` - read more on internet.